# Has the Brexit Party stated whether or not it will keep its name?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, parties, brexit-party

Has the Brexit Party made any statement on its name as a movement, when Brexit is finally resolved?

It would be expected after several years that 'Brexit' will have lost meaning. I can't think of any party in history becoming established and named by a "short-term" issue and going on to having an entrenched long term support or platform to stand on.

Comment: More importantly will Change UK have to change their name if they gain power and want things to then remain the same?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. It's a good idea to take the [Tour](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help). I doubt that this question is answerable as it stands, as it requires speculation which could not be verified with sources open to the public. If you can edit it to be more on topic for this site it stands a much better chance of staying open.

Comment: I voted to close as well. But you could edit your question and ask for public statements from members of the party about its future after an eventual Brexit, which would make the question on-topic (we cannot verify the future, checking if someone has said something in the past is considerably easier).

Comment: Interesting, it is sort of like voting to remove the possibility of someone with knowledge giving an answer based on the uninformed opinion that the knowledge does not exist.

Comment: I'm not criticizing the site guidelines, I never said anything about the site guidelines. If anything, I'm making an observation about the written comments.

Comment: One of the custom clossing reasons is specifically. *Questions asking for the internal motivations of people, how specific individuals would behave in hypothetical situations **or predictions for future events** are off-topic, because answers would be based on speculation and their correctness could not be verified with sources available to the public.* The people's comments are telling you what this site guidelines are.

Comment: Essentially you are saying "nobody knows the answer". How do you know that nobody knows whether or not the Brexit Party will keep its name after Brexit is over? It doesn't seem possible that 1 or 2 minutes after I pose the question that two experts arrive with instantaneous knowledge that the question can only be answered by speculation. Can you understand what I mean? It could be that Nigel Farage has publicly stated that he will change the name of the party or dissolve it entirely at some point and both you and I were not aware of this.

Comment: Because you are asking ***ABOUT THE FUTURE*** and nobody knows it for sure, specially when dealing with politics. **It is as simple as that**. You can see that the only answer you get is "they could do it... or they could not do it".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94021/discussion-between-brian-mcmahon-and-sjuan76).

Comment: I reworded the body in line with your title. It now asks about any statements from within the party. As such, it's less speculative.

Comment: Given they've not even published a manifesto (or "contract with the people" as Farage suggested), it isn't even clear that they have thought of anything but Brexit.

Comment: "I can't think of any party in history becoming established and named by a "short-term" issue".   Not quite, but the Conservative and Unionist party (aka Tory) was a merger of two parties, one of which was named for a position on a very specific issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On December 8th 2019, Farage [said](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/election-2019-50704706) in an interview with Sky News that after the UK leaves the European Union (as occurred on the 31st January 2020), the Brexit Party would change its name to the 'Reform Party', and would campaign "for changes to the voting system and the abolition of the House of Lords".

In the same interview, he said that he had already registered the name. However, a [search](http://search.electoralcommission.org.uk/Search/Registrations?currentPage=1&rows=30&query=reform%20party&sort=ApprovedDate&order=desc&open=filter&et=pp&et=ppm&register=gb&regStatus=registered&regStatus=deregistered&regStatus=lapsed&optCols=EntityStatusName) of the Electoral Commission records returns no trace of such a party having been registered by Farage or any of his associates. In addition, it does not appear to have been [rejected](https://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/who-we-are-and-what-we-do/party-registration-applications/party-registration-decisions), and is not listed in the record of [current applications](https://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/who-we-are-and-what-we-do/party-registration-applications/view-current-applications) either. A search of Companies House does return "[The Reform Party Limited](https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/SC649171)", but this company was registered after the interview, and none of the directors include Farage or any of his associates. In contrast, Farage is still a director of [The Brexit Party Limited](https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/11694875/officers).

So in conclusion, according to Nigel Farage, the new party will be called 'The Reform Party', and has already been registered. However it is unclear what Farage meant by 'registered', as neither Companies House nor the Electoral Commission seem to have any record of the registration.

**November 2020 Update:**

At the beginning of November, Brexit Party chairman Richard Tice along with leader Nigel Farage [published an article](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2020/11/01/relaunching-brexit-party-fight-cruel-unnecessary-lockdown/) in the Telegraph, stating that they would seek to rename the party to "Reform UK". Details of the application are not yet available on the Electoral Commission's website, however, the Telegraph also [published comments](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/politics/2020/11/01/exclusive-nigel-farage-relaunch-brexit-party-reform-uk-new-anti/) from the commission:

> On Sunday night a spokesman for the Electoral Commission said: "The
> Brexit Party has submitted an application to change its name to
> 'Reform UK'. If we are satisfied the application contains all of the
> information required by law, it will be published online. The
> application has yet to be assessed, this may take up to six weeks.
>
> "Applications to register a new political party name are subject to
> detailed assessment against the criteria set out in law. When we
> receive an application to register a new party name, the details of
> the new name are published online so members of the public can input
> their views."

**January 2021 Update:**

On January 4th, the Electoral Commission [approved](https://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/sites/default/files/2021-01/2021%20Party%20registration%20decisions-english%20version_0.pdf) The Brexit Party's application for the identity mark "Reform UK". This decision was published on the 6th, and comments from Farage were published by the [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-55566526):

> "This is great news and the perfect time in the New Year.
>
> "The need for reform is greater than ever as we try to recover from
> Covid.
>
> "We have a huge opportunity as a nation post-Brexit, but there are
> many areas of the UK that need real, bold reform: our economy, House
> of Lords, BBC, civil service, the voting system to mention a few."

Answer (score 8):

On your chief assumption of the Brexit party becoming a major party:

- If Brexit does not happen, they keep the name until it does happen, or the topic loses steam politically.
- If there is some kind of deal that effectively only takes the UK out in name only, but leaves all of the legal ties and responsibilities in place, the party keeps its name until a complete and proper Brexit happens, or the topic loses steam politically.
- If there is a no-deal Brexit, the party either dissolves completely (job done) or changes its name to some kind of patriotic based title and carries on under a different guise with a heavily modified agenda.

This is all speculation ofcourse based on an uncertain assumption.

Comment: Have they mentioned the possibility of dissolving if Brexit is brought to a conclusion that is satisfactory to the party?

Comment: @BrianMcMahon, I'd be amazed if anybody has thought that far ahead.

Comment: If no-deal Brexit happens being associated with it or considered responsible for the pointless mess would be a PR nightmare. Unless there would be really convincing way of shifting the blame, then such party would have to go into hiding.